# How to include the result of a combination function inside a Switch statement in ReactJS

Tags: javascript, reactjs, logic

I have an app that asks you for your interests and a user can put in any combination of 6 choices. I have the algorithm all done and working, but I'm not sure how I would translate that outcome into an React component.

My logic is as follows:

If a user picked the combination of `FE` and `UX` in the form of `['FE', 'UX']`, then display `<FEComponent>` AND `<UXComponent>`. 
Another example:

If a user picks `FE`, `UX`, and `BE`, the array would be `['FE', 'UX', 'BE']`, and the displayed components would be `<FEComponent>`, `<UXComponent>`, and `<BEComponent>`.

The data I'm working with is simply a single array with 6 potential options:

`['FE', 'BE', 'FS', 'GD', 'WD', 'UX']`

Here is the code I have thus far:

```
  const Dashboard = ({
  getCurrentProfile,
  deleteAccount,
  auth: { user },
  profile: { profile, status, location, skills, interests }
}) => {
  useEffect(() => {
    getCurrentProfile();
  }, [getCurrentProfile]);

  const profileShow = profile !== null ? console.log(profile.interests) : null;

  return (
    <>
      <Container fluid>
        <Row>
          <Col lg={12}>
            {profile !== null ? (
              <Container>
                <h2>Dashboard</h2>
                <p>
                  Here are all the resources we have put together for you so you
                  can make the best of your tech career!
                </p>
              </Container>
            ) : (
              <Container>
                <h2 className="text-center">Just a few questions for ya!</h2>
                <p className="text-center">
                  To better your experience, answer these few questions
                </p>
                <ProfileForm />
              </Container>
            )}
          </Col>
        </Row>
      </Container>
    </>
  );
};
```

And here is a screenshot of what I'm describing:

[image]

Comment: Can you provide all the code that bridges the gap from `k_combinations` to *anything* in react?

Comment: I updated it @DrewReese

Comment: So are you looking to render `<ShowFrontEndAndUX/>` if an array contains both of `FE` and `UX`? I suppose it was implicitly stated, but you should include *how* the data/result relates to the rendered JSX.

Comment: That's exactly what I'm looking for yes. I didn't work it very straightforward, sorry @DrewReese

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand your desired behavior then I think this will get you close to what you're after.

(1) Create a map of type combos to Component, example

```
const comboComponentMap = {
  FE: FEComponent,
  BE: BEComponent,
  FS: FSComponent,
  GD: GDComponent,
  WD: WDComponent,
  UX: UXComponent
};
```

(2) Map *some* array of selected/checked/etc.. types to the component you want to display

```
typesArray.map(type => {
  const Component = comboComponentMap[type];
  return <Component key={type} />;
})
```

Example: given `["FE", "UX"]`

```
<FEComponent />
<UXComponent />
```

Example: given `["FE", "BE", "UX"]`

```
<FEComponent />
<BEComponent />
<UXComponent />
```

Rough Demo

[image: Edit great-field-3pu2o]

Comment: this is good, but it isn't working with ALL of the array options. There are 63 arrays, so I would need to make a component for each array

Comment: I'm thinking of something along the lines of "If the combo has FE in it, then show FE Resources, then if that's true, go to the next option, BE, and if it has BE in it then show BE as well, and then continue with all the options"

Comment: @Alyssa Solution is just a small sample of the mapping required for the entire data array, to get you started. What you now describe is different than your question. It sounds more like you just want to map each option of a "combo" to a component, i.e. combo `["FE", "BE"]` simply maps to `[<FEResource />, <BEResource />]` JSX. Please go ahead and update your question with a more precise expected output.

Comment: @Alyssa Updated answer and sandbox. Still a minimal demo. I'm still not quite understand the whole dataset you had posted, but perhaps it isn't as relevant since it seems you are trying to render *one set* of type. Let me know if this is closer.